# CSUPLOAD Error: Cannot find the VM Role Agent-Failed the verification tests

Tags: azure

I'm about ready to cry so any help is appreciated:

I have prepared a VM Role, installed the Azure Integration Tools and run the sysprep, running csupload from a 64bit command prompt machine, but still am getting this error:
Cannot find the VM Role Agent
Failed the verification test
Cannot prepare VHD.....

I tried just bypassing with skipverify, but when trying to run, the instance is declared unhealthy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install Windows Azure Integration Components into your VM from a matching Windows Azure SDK version as the csupload you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to check the Version of the SDK

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/af9ecd64-5c88-4745-b4f1-a227485fead0